# Print double quotations with WshShell.Sendkeys and windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters, escaping, wsh

I have a script that changes the users directory and prefills the input with a command, so he only has to look it over and change values before pressing enter. The command that's going to be written requires double quotations and I cannot get it to print this in the input. I've tried various of escape characters like ^", \", "", """ and {"} but I get none of them to work. I use the WshShell for this but if it's not possible using it and there's a better way that will solve this then I'm all ears.

The goal is that the user will see this in command window:

```
command.exe parameter="hello" parameter2="world"
```

The .bat file:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
rem Start cmd.exe program 
start "" cmd
rem Send whatever you want to previous cmd.exe
%SendKeys% "echo Hello World!{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "cd C:\temp{ENTER}"
%SendKeys% "command.exe parameter="hello" parameter2="world""
set /P "="
ECHO TERMINATE ORIGINAL BATCH
goto :EOF
@end
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Source for batscript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22772040/1350598

Comment: It is not a sendkeys problem.  It is how arguments are parsed when they are passed to the jscript. So I would suggest you make the quotes some other character then do a replace on the argument you pass to replace that character to chr(34).  Then use that value for the sendkeys.

Comment: @Squashman Thanks for reply and tip! I've pursued what you suggesting here and tried creating a new variable and replace char with quotation without luck. I've tried a few variations but to take an example: var test = "com.exe parameter=qhelloq"  replace(string, chr(34), "q")  %SendKeys% test

Comment: Normally the character you want to replace comes first.  I have never seen it reversed in any language I have programmed in.  I am not overly familiar with Jscript so I could be wrong.

Comment: Use `%SendKeys% "'command.exe parameter=\u0022hello\u0022 parameter2=\u0022world\u0022'"` and change the last line by `WshShell.SendKeys(eval(WScript.Arguments(0)));`. Note that you need to add the apostrophe `'` at begin-end of all strings.

Comment: @Aacini Thanks Aacini! That seems to work! It doesn't include the other sendkey commands like changing folder but I could write the full path of the command. Suggest it as answer and I'll tag it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%SendKeys% "'command.exe parameter=\u0022hello\u0022 parameter2=\u0022world\u0022'"` and change the last line by `WshShell.SendKeys(eval(WScript.Arguments(0)));`. Note that you need to add the apostrophe `'` at begin-end of all strings; that is:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then
@echo off
rem Use %SendKeys% to send keys to the keyboard buffer
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
rem Start cmd.exe program 
start "" cmd
rem Send whatever you want to previous cmd.exe
%SendKeys% "'echo Hello World!{ENTER}'"
%SendKeys% "'cd C:\temp{ENTER}'"
%SendKeys% "'command.exe parameter=\u0022hello\u0022 parameter2=\u0022world\u0022'"
set /P "="
ECHO TERMINATE ORIGINAL BATCH
goto :EOF
@end
var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(eval(WScript.Arguments(0)));
```